# How to force a dependent task to start the next day?

Tags: microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2010

I would like the start date of a dependent task to start the next day, even if the predecessor task finishes a little early the previous day. Unfortunately the successor task always starts (assuming an FS dependency) immediately after the predecessor task.

[image: Sample]

In this example, even if Task 3 finishes on Jan 2 at 12:00 PM, I do not wish for the Client review task to start on Jan 2, instead to start the starting (8:00 AM) of the following day. Is there a way I can force this?

Thanks,
Sean

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in MSP. The nearest your can get, assuming for example that all your tasks are <1 day in length, is to make the second task a predecessor of the first using a start-start relationship with a lag of 1d. In effective this says "start the second task one day later than the start of the first task, no matter on which day Task 1 starts...

But that is unlikely to be useful as if Task 1 starts a 10:30 on Day 1, Task 2 will start at 10:30 on Day 2, not 09:00 on Day 2.

Or you can muck around with Start No Earlier than constraints on all the subsequent tasks, but that is going to be a PITA for anything more than one instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the Hours per Day to be 9 hours in Change Working Time -> Options.

So that you don't have any breaks and match start and end time.

Comment: I don’t understand how this can possibly work.  Can you explain? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Add an appropriate amount of **elapsed** time to the predecessor link.
In your example, Client Review Task's predecessor can be "3FS+8eh"
Assuming there are 8 working hours per day in the project plan, adding 8 elapsed hours to the **driving** predecessor link will push the task to the start of the next working day.